# Open only GIMP's color selector or open it directly upon invocation?

Tags: gimp

I like GIMP's color selector, which pops up as a dialog window when one clicks a color square in GIMP's toolbox.

[image: Color selector]

Is there a way to launch only the color selector without the overhead of loading GIMP? If not, can I specify from the command-line that I want to open the color selector straight away?

Comment: Not sure about GIMP, but alternatives exist - `gpick` or `mate-color-select`.

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert, I'm wondering about GIMP specifically to avoid having 2 programs that do the same thing.

Comment: (... Though I'm aware modern programs are departing from the good old Unix principle of modularization ...)

Comment: You have to check Script-Fu and/or Python-Fu to find and utilize possibly existing GIMP scripts.

Comment: It appears to be a GtkWidget gimp_color_dialog_new https://github.com/GNOME/gimp/blob/master/app/widgets/gimpcolordialog.c

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but there is no way to activate the feature without opening the application.
I prefer to use the Adobe website to choose trendy colors [Click to try it](https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1179534)